# How to uninstall Ubuntu and windows 10?

Tags: grub2, windows-8, reinstall

So I have a dual system windows and ubuntu. My booting is from GRUB. I want to have a fresh start, eg. uninstall both and then install window and make ubuntu in my virtual box. What steps should I take? Please help. I'm new. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

this is simple,

you may use [easyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) on windows and set only one boot entry for windows and then you use the disk manager from windows to format the ubuntu partitions.

or, you reinstall windows and then you format the Ubuntu partitions from the disk manager in windows.